# Having trouble with an index in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two fields that I am using for a percentage calculation.  This is a simple one-liner.

```
x = df.groupby(['brand'])['result'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

That gives a series which looks like this:

```
brand         result  
0             positive    0.816692
              neutral     0.105067
              negative    0.078241
37 Actives    positive    0.746835
              negative    0.126582

iS CLINICAL   neutral     0.085824
jane iredale  positive    1.000000
skyn ICELAND  positive    0.777778
              neutral     0.166667
              negative    0.055556
```

I converted this to a dataframe.  Now, what I would like to do is add an Index and update the field names to brand, result, percent.

I tried three ways to work with the Index.

```
x = x.reset_index(drop=True)
x.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
x.index = range(len(x.index))
```

In all three instances, the brand and result are gone and all I have left is the percent.  How can I just add a numbered Index, and name the three fields accordingly?  Thanks.

Comment: You're explicitly telling it to replace the existing index with the new one. True changing to `drop=False`

Comment: I tried that and got this: ValueError: cannot insert result, already exists

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue. If I use your data and create a dataframe called `df` with a multiindex of `brand` and `result`, then run `df.reset_index()` I get all of the data in all of the 3 columns with a numeric index from 0 to 9